# Adding text to inline-block div forces it to float downwards

Tags: html, css

If I have the following HTML

```
<div class="one">
    Test
</div>
<div class="two">

</div>
<div class="three">

</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
    height:30px;
    width:100px;
}

.one,
.three
{
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

.two
{
 background-color:#EEEEEE;
}
```

the three div's do not sit next to each other [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cwjja/2/):

[image]

Why and how do I stop this?

Remove the text and they look like I wish them to look, [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cwjja/3/):

[image]

Comment: Use `vertical-align:middle` on the `div`s

Comment: This or the answer below seems to fix this. Ta @Paulie_D !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the vertical-align property  on the divs to top:

```
div {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cwjja/6/)**

Comment: Seems to fix this it. Any explanation or is it just one of them quirks?

Comment: It has to do with inline and inline-block elements having a default vertical alignment of baseline and it being triggered by your text being added to the div.